# Android (Java/Kotlin) - Http error 400 - Bad Request and the request have only header without body

Tags: java, android, kotlin, httpurlconnection

everyone!

I've been building and app that consumes an API from the company where I work. When I perform a request (GET) with URL connection (through HttpURlConnection) with header (encoding, authorization and etc.) AND a body (as a JSON, using Content-Type = "application/json") the response code is 200 and the connection works pretty good, but and I use the same header in another request BUT WITHOUT a content, I get a Bad Request.

I already tried setting the doOutout = false, but It doesn't work.

I think that everything is OK with the URL and the header because I performed the request by Postman and I got the response.

Here is the way I'm creating the connection and connecting:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("Base URL").buildUpon().appendPath(path).build() val url = URL(uri.toString()) val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection connection.apply {
            addRequestProperty("Charset", Charsets.UTF_8.displayName())
            addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic $token")
            addRequestProperty("X-Serial", 5036.toString())
            requestMethod = "GET"
            connectTimeout = 0
            readTimeout = 0
            doOutput = false
            if (responseCode != HTTP_OK) throws Exception("Erro") 
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible to see the JSON structure of the failing request and response?

Comment: @EamonScullion, in this, this request there's no JSON. As response, the JSON'd look like this:

[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Nome": "Name"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Nome": "Name"
    }
]

This is the exception:
     Caused by: br.com.company.app.api.resource.ResponseException: Erro da conexão com a API!
    
    Causa: 400: Bad Request
        at br.com.company.app.api.resource.BaseClient.verifyResponseError(BaseClient.kt:32)
        at br.com.company.app.api.resource.BandeirasClient.listarBandeiras(BandeirasClient.kt:39)

Comment: I don't know if the request property X-Serial is valid for a HttpUrlConnection.
This API is working in as App made in C# for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Bad Request suggest that it's an issue with the way your request is formed.

It is likely a problem with one of the request headers that you are setting. Have a look at the accepted request headers [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Charset should potentially be named Accept-Charset, and I haven't seen any examples of X-Serial being used.

[Here](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-httpurlconnection-example/) is an example of setting up a GET request using HttpUrlConnection. You could try removing all headers apart from Authorization and setting the request method to GET, like in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem: Me!
The $token value was generate with the flag DEFAULT. After I realized that, I putted the flag NO_WRAP and my request worked.

My bad! But thanks for all support!